# Custom list in c#

Tags: c#

I need to create a list that hold something like

```
public List<int,bool> PostionAndChecked
{ get; set; }
```

and then a list

```
public List<int> PageNumber
        { get; set; }
```

So what should happen is the each page number in the PageNumber list should be linked to the PostionAndChecked list

How do i do this?

Comment: is the int unique in the list?

Comment: How would i then add items to the PostionAndChecked Tuple<int, bool>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List` is a list of one type, not two. You can use a `Tuple<int, bool>`, or you can use a `Dictionary<int, bool>`.

Although, since you just need to hold a bit for each number, you might be satisfied with using a `Set<int>`, adding only the `true` numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Dictionary<int, bool>`, this will store the `Key` (`int`) and the corresponding `Value` (`bool`), without the need to do your own indexing. So for the above you would have

```
public Dictionary<int, bool> lookup { get; set; } 
...
lookup = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
```

add new entries to this like

```
lookup.Add(0, true);
lookup.Add(1, false);
...
```

You can then reference the `Boolean` value based upon the relevent index as follows

```
bool b = lookup[someIndex];
```

For more information on this calss see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The following is suitable only as an illustration especially if the int is unique in your list of pages to check. Hopefully, you should be able to see how this might be changed to suit your purposes.

It is not obvious to me why you need another list storing page numbers, maybe you could explain why you think you need it?

```
public class PageChecker
{
    public IDictionary<int, bool> PositionAndChecked { get; set; }

    public PageChecker()
    {
        SetUpPages();
    }

    private void SetUpPages()
    {
        PositionAndChecked = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        var pageCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            PositionAndChecked.Add(i, false);
        }
    }

    public void CheckPage(int pageNo)
    {
        PositionAndChecked[pageNo] = true;
    }
}
```